# No known class method for selector 'initWith...'

Tags: objective-c

I found similar questions, but I couldn't solve my error. My error is:

> No known class method for selector 'initWithUrl:sub:cont:cat:dat'

I've tried

- `@Synthesize`,
- `self.variableName` instead of `_variableName`,
- adding `[[MyClass init] alloc]`,
- changing `-` to `+`

How can I fix it?

MyClass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(id)init;
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url_ sub:(NSString *)subject_ cont:(NSString *)content_ cat:(NSString *)category_ dat:(NSString *)date_;

@property NSURL *bannerImageURL;
@property NSString *subject;
@property NSString *content;
@property NSString *category;
@property NSString *date;

@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _bannerImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url0"];
        _subject = @"sub0";
        _content = @"cont0";
        _category = @"cat0";
        _date = @"dat0";
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url_ sub:(NSString *)subject_ cont:(NSString *)content_ cat:(NSString *)category_ dat:(NSString *)date_ {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _bannerImageURL = url_;
        _subject = subject_;
        _content = content_;
        _category = category_;
        _date = date_;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

myViewController.m:

```
#import "myViewController.h"
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation SimpleTableViewController

MyClass *news1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"aUrl"];

    // Error occurs here.
    news1 = [MyClass initWithURL:aUrl sub:@"aSub" cont:@"aCont" cat:@"aCat" dat:@"aDat"];
}
```

Comment: change the - to a plus to make a class method in the class header. ie +(id)initWithURL etc.  otherwise you need to call a regular allocator and then the initializer on the instance.

Comment: @johnelemans I just changed - to + in MyClass.h file. Then I got an warning "Method definition for 'initWithURL...' not found". Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
news1 = [[MyClass alloc] initWithURL:aUrl sub:@"aSub" cont:@"aCont" cat:@"aCat" dat:@"aDat"];
```

This is a standard pattern in Objective-C: call `[SomeClass alloc]` to create a new instance, then immediately call some initializer method on it. Initializers are *instance methods* which must be called on an instance of a class, whereas `alloc` is a *class method* that is called on the class itself (and which returns a newly allocated instance of that class).